# What's the longest expected service life for PC laptop batteries

Tags: laptop, battery

Have there been studies on which manufacturer's battery lasts better for the long term? I'm thinking of a comparison like they do with hard drive wear-and-tear.

I'm not after who could give me the longest "unplug time", but rather "service life". I'm not very mobile---I almost only unplug when I'm at conferences/meet-ups---but I'd like to know which one  could keep up the same amount of unplug time for the longest number of years.

(I specified PC because because, for laptops in general, I think Macbooks is a no-brainer answer. Impressed as I am with Apple battery, I still prefer to work with PCs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is not very succinct; as there are numerous factors that come into play. If you *really* want to know then I suggest reading [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1snzg1/is_it_actually_bad_for_the_battery_of_a_laptop_to/) Reddit post that does a good job framing the various factors that contribute to the answer of your question.

I would also focus more on the hardware of your system than the battery, as it will play a bigger role in the life of battery. I have really good battery life with Macbook Air, and Macbooks in general. Lenovo T series laptops do a great job as well.